# Is the Alexandrov compactification of the integers basically disconnected?

Tags: general-topology

Is the Alexandrov compactification of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ (with the usual Euclidean distance) basically disconnected?

Comment: What is the topology you're using on $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @H. Potter Sorry I meant the usual Euclidean topology.

Comment: Learned a new word today: "basically disconnected" http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0219.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following function

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 \qquad \text{if } x \text{ is even or  }\infty\\
1/x \qquad \text{else}
\end{cases}. $$

This is continous since the closed sets $A$ of the Alexandroff-Compactification are of the form $A=M\cup \infty$ where $M\subset \mathbb{Z}$ is arbitrary or $A$=finite union of points in $\mathbb{Z}$.

But now the cozero set of $f$ is the odd numbers and there closure by the above description is $\{\text{odd numbers}\}\cup \infty$ which is not a open set in the topology of the Alexandroff-Compactification.

Comment: Thanks. It seems so obvious now! Thanks again.